# How much functor is representable？

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I know a few examples of representable functors, for example, forgetful functor from group to set, ring of witt vectors, and taking derivative of modules.

I would like to know representable functor is rare or commonplace？

Comment: One of the key points of modern homotopy theory development is to make certain functors representable.

Comment: In algebraic geometry, I think representable functors are rather rare and representability theorems are highly valued.

Comment: otoh, *many* functors doing interesting things are representable. (And yes, they are doing interesting things *because* they are)

Comment: In category theory proper, universal properties (adjunctions, limits etc.) can be stated in terms of certain functors being representable.